# How to recursively delete objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I would like to delete all `.JPEG` files from specified path at S3 bucket. For example, lets say that I have structure on S3 cloud service similar to following:

```
Obj1/
   Obj2/
      Obj3/
         image_1.jpeg
         ...
         image_N.jpeg
```

Is it possible to specify `Obj1/Obj2/Obj3` as `DeleteObjectsInput's` `prefix` and recursively delete all `.JPEG` files that contain such `prefix`.

Here is my code:

```
func (s3Obj S3) Delete() error {
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(s3Obj.Region),
    }))
    svc := s3.New(sess)

    input := &s3.DeleteObjectsInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(s3Obj.Bucket),
        Delete: &s3.Delete{
            Objects: []*s3.ObjectIdentifier{
                {
                    Key: aws.String(s3Obj.ItemPath),
                },
            },
            Quiet: aws.Bool(false),
        },
    }

    result, err := svc.DeleteObjects(input)
    if err != nil {
        if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
            switch aerr.Code() {
            default:
                glog.Errorf("Error occurred while trying to delete object from S3. Error message - %v", aerr.Error())
            }
        } else {
            glog.Errorf("Error occurred while trying to delete object from S3. Error message - %v", err.Error())
        }
        return err
    }

    glog.Info(result)
    return nil
}
```

`sObj3.ItemPath` represents `Obj1/Obj2/Obj3` path from example above. As a result of this function I do not get any error. I actually get the following message:

```
Deleted: [{
      Key: "Obj1/Obj2/Obj3"
    }]
```

But when I check my S3 cloud service, nothing is done. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I've changed my code so my Delete function accepts list of objects from which I make a list of `s3.ObjectIdentifier`. There is roughly 50 .JPEG files in that list, and for some reason following code **ONLY DELETES LAST ONE**. I am not sure why.

```
func (s3Obj S3) Delete(objects []string) error {
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(s3Obj.Region),
    }))
    svc := s3.New(sess)

    var objKeys = make([]*s3.ObjectIdentifier, len(objects))
    for i, v := range objects {
        glog.Info("About to delete: ", v)
        objKeys[i] = &s3.ObjectIdentifier{
            Key: &v,
        }
    }

    input := &s3.DeleteObjectsInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(s3Obj.Bucket),
        Delete: &s3.Delete{
            Objects: objKeys,
            Quiet:   aws.Bool(false),
        },
    }

    result, err := svc.DeleteObjects(input)
    if err != nil {
        if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
            switch aerr.Code() {
            default:
                glog.Errorf("Error occurred while trying to delete object from S3. Error message - %v", aerr.Error())
            }
        } else {
            glog.Errorf("Error occurred while trying to delete object from S3. Error message - %v", err.Error())
        }
        return err
    }

    glog.Info(result)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: No, there is no recursive delete in the S3 API.

Comment: How is it suppose to be done then? I would have to first List all of keys on specified path and then call Delete where I pass previously generated list of keys?

Comment: Yes, that's how it's done.

Comment: To reduce the pain of listing objects, you might consider using S3 Inventory, then perform a batch delete on 100s of objects at a time. Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/679989/most-efficient-way-to-batch-delete-s3-files

Comment: I have updated a question. Could you please take a look and if you know the answer to it please post it so I can accept it and close the question. @Adrian

Comment: Could you please take a look as well @jarmod